# Error while writing terraform script while making eks fargate profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, amazon-eks

```
aws_iam_role.example: Creating...
    ╷
    │ Error: error creating IAM Role (eks-fargate-profile-example): AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::352316401451:user/EKScluster is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::352316401451:role/eks-fargate-profile-example with an explicit deny
    │       status code: 403, request id: eaece782-dd14-4632-9d9c-86e31db4081b
    │
    │   with aws_iam_role.example,
    │   on main.tf line 25, in resource "aws_iam_role" "example":
    │   25: resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
```

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "example" {
  cluster_name           =var.cluster_name
  fargate_profile_name   = "example"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids = data.aws_subnet.example[*].id

  selector {
    namespace = "example"
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "eks-fargate-profile-example"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Service = "eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
    Version = "2012-10-17"
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example.name
}
```

Comment: It seems the user you are trying to run terraform with is not authorized to perform the action of `iam:CreateRole`.

Comment: can you post the provider configurations?